# Psi Function ("digamma") in golang

Tags: go, scientific-computing, lda

I've been searching for a scientific computing library for golang that implements the digamma function, which is the logarithmic derivative of the gamma function.

I've attempted to implement the function myself, but I can only find explicit formulas for the digamma function evaluated at integers, but I need to be able to evaluate it at non-integer numbers.

Is anyone aware of a scientific computing package for go or of a precise formula for digamma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I ported some other simpler C Code from [here](http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~mjohnson/code/digamma.c). Might have been a slight copout, but I didn't want to deal with all the dependencies in the GSL code suggested by Marc, and I don't have much experience with C so it would have been an ordeal.  This code tests successfully against wolfram alpha, though, so it may not be too much of a tradeoff.

I put the little file on github, though it's not a go package. Just a simple file that implements the function and has a main routine that tests it.

Here's the [link](https://github.com/sinwav/PsiGo/blob/master/digamma.go) to that.  Thanks to Brett Beutell for the help.

Comment: Okay, cool. I found further evidence that the series approach is accurate in some c++ code from an open source Topic Modeling project by yahoo.  Their implementation of digamma uses the first seven terms in the series approximation (where ours uses four terms).  Their code is [here](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/Yahoo_LDA/blob/master/src/commons/TopicLearner/Dirichlet.cpp) (link to github)

Answer (score 1):

I have looked through github, gitbucket & godoc with no avail for over 1 hour, I can assert with almost 100% certainty there is no go implementation for the Digamma function.

Your best bet would be to port the GSL C Code found [here](http://fossies.org/dox/gsl-1.16/psi_8c_source.html).

Comment: This seems to be the right call at this point.  I will hopefully have this ported to Go by the end of the weekend and will post a github link here. But bandaids can only go so far. At some point, Go will need a sweeping scientific computing package along the lines of GSL or Scipy....

Answer (score 0):

Here is another implementation ported from C++/Boost: [Digamma](https://github.com/pbenner/autodiff/blob/master/special/digamma.go)